# Migrating JSP (Server Side) to Client Side rendering like Angular JS, Backbone JS

Tags: angularjs, jsp, migration, client-side, server-side

I would like to move from server-side rendering view technologies like JSP, Struts to client-side rendering view technologies using Angular JS, Backbone JS.
We can do that by redeveloping the application using Restful API's and Angular JS.
But it will take high efforts in the migration. Do we have any tool/technique which could reduce the effort taken in the redevelopment?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions regarding tool suggestions for efforts such as this are considered off topic for this site because they are primarily opinion-based. If you have questions about how a specific tools works, that would be appropriate to ask here. Here's a link to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: What tools would you expect? They work completely differently

Comment: Yes that's correct, still wanted to see if there is any.